# How to reset a LG V20 phone

Tags: lg

I recently has my LCD screen repaired on my new LG V20, The third part repairman eventually deleted all of my data and locked the phone out due to putting in the wrong screen swipe too many times. The phone was synced to a GOOGLE account which is no longer active and the phone can be restored without that login and password.Is there anyway for me to restore the factory settings and rset the phone?

Comment: Plug the phone into a PC and wipe it with the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into recovery mode and wipe the phone from there.

1) Make sure that you already powered off your phone before you take any further step.

2) Press and hold “Power button” and “Volume Down button” for several seconds until LG logo appear on the screen.

3) When LG logo appear, release the buttons then press them again until recovery mode loads.

You can move around in recovery mode by pressing the volume up and down buttons. There should be a wipe/reset option in recovery mode which can be used to set the phone back to default factory settings.